# Enterprise Architect 32 bit comdlg DLL or equivalent for 64 bit windows 2008R2

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to write some scripts for Enterprise Architect and I need one to save a file.  Running on Windows 2008R2 (64 bit) the script crashes because it can't find MSComDlg.

Apparently this is not shipped with recent versions of Windows.  What is an alternative (note 32 bit process on 64 bit O/S) that is accessible to the scripting engine?